# Get a single item from RestAPI using id as parameter in Flutter

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart, rest

I hope you all are doing safe. I have successfully implemented `getContactList()` from Rest API in `ListView` but now I want to get a single contact item when I click on a particular contact list item and display its fields in a `TextFormField` in flutter by passing the contact `id` as a parameter. I'm new to flutter and coding in general so I hope I could get my solution here. Thank You.

**Sample Json Data:**

```
{
    "total": "1",
    "contacts": {
        "193208": {
            "isPublished": true,
            "dateAdded": "2017-11-14T17:21:47+05:30",
            "dateModified": "2017-11-14T17:33:51+05:30",
            "createdBy": 4,
            "createdByUser": "Arul raj",
            "modifiedBy": 4,
            "modifiedByUser": "Arul raj",
            "id": 193208,
            "points": 0,
            "color": null,
            "fields": {
                "core": {
                    "points": {
                        "id": "47",
                        "label": "Points",
                        "alias": "points",
                        "type": "number",
                        "group": "core",
                        "object": "lead",
                        "is_fixed": "1",
                        "value": "0"
                    },
                    "firstname": {
                        "id": "2",
                        "label": "First Name",
                        "alias": "firstname",
                        "type": "text",
                        "group": "core",
                        "object": "lead",
                        "is_fixed": "1",
                        "value": "Richa"
                    },
                    "lastname": {
                        "id": "3",
                        "label": "Last Name",
                        "alias": "lastname",
                        "type": "text",
                        "group": "core",
                        "object": "lead",
                        "is_fixed": "1",
                        "value": "Kumari"
                    },
                    "...": {
                        "...": "...",
                    },
                    {
                        ....
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

**API_Manager.dart:**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:aritic/models/singleContactModel.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:aritic/models/contactsModel.dart';
import 'dart:developer' as developer;

// ignore: camel_case_types
class API_Manager {
  Future<ContactsModel> getContacts() async {
    var client = http.Client();
    var contactsModel;
    String contacts_url =
        'https://example.com/api/contacts';
    String basicAuth = 'Basic exampleauthkey';
    try {
      var response = await client.get(contacts_url,
          headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});
      //print(response.statusCode);
      //developer.log(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonString = response.body;
        var jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
        contactsModel = ContactsModel.fromJson(jsonMap);
      }
    } catch (Exception) {
      return contactsModel;
    }
    return contactsModel;
  }

  Future<ContactsModel> getSingleContact(String id) async {
    var client = http.Client();
    var singleContactModel;
    String singleContactUrl =
        'https://example.com/api/contacts/id';
    String basicAuth = 'Basic exampleauthkey';
    try {
      var response = await client.get(singleContactUrl,
          headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});
      print(response.statusCode);
      //developer.log(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonString = response.body;
        var jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
        singleContactModel = SingleContactModel.fromJson(jsonMap);
      }
    } catch (Exception) {
      return singleContactModel;
    }
    return singleContactModel;
  }
}
```

**View Single contact UI Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:aritic/services/api_manager.dart';

class ViewContact extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _ViewContactState createState() => _ViewContactState();
}

class _ViewContactState extends State<ViewContact> {
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    API_Manager().getSingleContact();   //Need to pass id as parameter here
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFDAE0E2),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        title: Text("View Contact"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            _topContainer(),
            DefaultTabController(
                length: 4, // length of tabs
                initialIndex: 0,
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: TabBar(
                          isScrollable: false,
                          unselectedLabelColor:
                              Colors.blueGrey[700].withOpacity(1),
                          labelColor: Colors.black,
                          indicatorColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
                          labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
                          tabs: [
                            Tab(text: 'Activity'),
                            Tab(text: 'Associations'),
                            Tab(text: 'About'),
                            Tab(text: 'Attachments'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      _bottomContainer(),
                    ])),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _bottomContainer() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
          height: 400, //height of TabBarView
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                  top: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.grey, width: 0.5))),
          child: TabBarView(children: <Widget>[
            _activityContainer(),
            _associationsContainer(),
            _aboutContainer(),
            _attachmentsContainer()
          ])),
    );
  }

  Widget _aboutContainer() {
    return Container(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 3,
              ),
              Text('About Contact',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              SizedBox(
                width: 90,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 30,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey[700])),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  color: Color(0xFFC9E8E9).withOpacity(0.5),
                  textColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text("Edit Contact",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 3,
              ),
            ]),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                readOnly: true,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'First Name',
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    filled: true,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                readOnly: true,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Last Name',
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    filled: true,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                readOnly: true,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Email',
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    filled: true,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                readOnly: true,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Phone Number',
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    filled: true,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*I've removed all the unnecessary UI code and kept only the ones which will usable here.*

**EDIT,
All contacts Page:**

```
FutureBuilder<ContactsModel>(
                      future: _contactsModel,
                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                          AsyncSnapshot<ContactsModel> snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return ListView.separated(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.contacts.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              List keys = snapshot.data.contacts.keys.toList();
                              List values =
                                  snapshot.data.contacts.values.toList();
                              var contact = values[index]; //Single contact object here
                              final contactID = contact.id.toString();
                              return InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (_) => ViewContact(contact, contactID)));
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 50,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        contact.fields.all.firstname +
                                            " " +
                                            contact.fields.all.lastname,
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            separatorBuilder:
                                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return SizedBox(
                                height: 5,
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        } else
                          return Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
                                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                      Colors.cyan)));
                      }),
```

Comment: Didn't understand it properly, if you are getting response in list form then why we need api call again, can't we pass same in object form to next page and read it , for example if json we are getting for contact list it means we do have single-single object of contact which makes it contact list correct, could you please elaborate more , I am working on this kind of things from past 4 years in flutter, probably I can help on same

Comment: The response is not in list, I have only implemented the response I got of all the contacts in the `ListView`,but now I have to get the response for each contact by id. I understand what you said I can use the same response and pass single contact object directly but then how would I differentiate those contacts with each other? Like if I click on one contact it should go to another page of that contact details. Similarly for other objects, so to achieve this I have to pass the contact ID along with the object as parameter to the next page but I have no clue how to actually implement that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the whole contact details using index and refer it from ViewContact(contactData) page ,then you have to add that controller to your textform feilds

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:aritic/services/api_manager.dart';

class ViewContact extends StatefulWidget {
 final contactData;
 ViewContact(this.contactData);

@override
_ViewContactState createState() => _ViewContactState();
}
```

then you have to set all the textfeild controller to your data like

```
class _ViewContactState extends State<ViewContact> {
 bool isLoading = false;

  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  TextEditingController name = TextEditingController();
    @override
    void initState() { 
      super.initState();
      name.text = widget.contactData.personNameexample
      }
TextFormField(
            readOnly: true,
            controller:name
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Last Name',
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
          ),
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I got one half of it correct to use the controller and display the details but I'm still having trouble with passing the single contact object as a whole and the contact ID as parameters to the next page. Hope you can help mw with that.

Comment: can you add the code of all contact screen here? so i can guid you

Comment: oh sure, will do that. I've edited the post

Comment: you dont have to send the contact id from here. it is already there inside the contact data, so first make sure contact has the data. before calling the page route call print(contact) if data is printed in your terminal you can follow the given answer to single contact page